# Authorization forbidden when using Orbeon eXist DB REST API

Tags: api, rest, authorization, orbeon, exist-db

I'm new to Orbeon 4.1 and I'm trying to query the Orbeon eXist DB from an external application. 
When I query for a form instance I keep getting a "not authorized" error. For example:

```
GET request:

http://localhost:8080/orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test-app/test-form/data/9b9b4f73af642fe042ec4cf7b4f03c64fa15fbd4/data.xml

Response:

HTTP Error 403 (Forbidden): The server refused to fulfill the request.
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I ended up installing eXist-db as a stand-alone webapp. Now I can query the eXist-db REST API directly and everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is because since version 4, services are [protected by default](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/40#TOC-Authorization-of-pages-and-services), as you most likely don't want your users to be able to access eXist or the persistence services. You can [open those services again](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/page-flow-controller/authorization#TOC-Backward-compatibility), but instead, it is better to [setup an authorization service](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/page-flow-controller/authorization#TOC-Authorization-service), and have whoever calls the services authenticate itself.

Comment: Right now I'm not concerned about security. I edited the local-properties.xml in order open the webservices, but I could not make it work. I ended up installing a stand-alone eXist-db and now I can query the eXist-db services directly.